# Pulling Data from Google spreadsheet

Tags: dashing

I am having difficulty pulling data from Google spreadsheet

I have added following gem files

```
gem 'roo'
gem 'google_drive'
gem 'google-spreadsheet-ruby'
```

---

My jobs file is 
    require 'roo'
    require 'rubygems'

```
def fetch_spreadsheet_data()
    google_user = "MY EMAIL ADDRESS"
    google_password = "MY PASSWORD"

    workbook = Roo::Google.new("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=1hdwnrDsuJId1FLE0yWICYP1HGqYNu2NHH2IcoPyAzOQ#gid=0",user: google_user, password: google_password)
    send_event('catchup_data', {current: s.cell('B',2) })
    send_event('Bounced_back', {current: s.cell('B',3) )
end


SCHEDULER.every '5m' do
    fetch_spreadsheet_data()
end
```

---

My dashboard.erb file has following html

```
  <li data-row="2" data-col="3" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
    <div data-id="bounce_back" data-view="Number" data-title="Triage - Work in Progress" style="background-color:#5AC352;"></div>
  </li>

 <li data-row="2" data-col="4" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
    <div data-id="catchup_data" data-view="Number" data-title="Squad catchup sessions last month" style="background-color:#DBA901;"></div>
  </li>
```

Not sure what am I missing that the data is not coming through. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong that I can see:

1. You're sending 'Bounced_back' but binding to the id of 'bounce_back'
2. You are trying to get the cell data from 's' but 's' is undefined

Looking at the Roo docs, I believe you have copied 's' from there. Just above that, they use sheet instead so I believe you have to grab the sheet from the workbook before using it.

I googled a bit and found this: http://etzelstorfer.com/en/dashing-graph-from-google-spreadsheet/

In summary, this should work for you:

```
def fetch_spreadsheet_data()
    google_user = "MY EMAIL ADDRESS"
    google_password = "MY PASSWORD"

    workbook = Roo::Google.new("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=1hdwnrDsuJId1FLE0yWICYP1HGqYNu2NHH2IcoPyAzOQ#gid=0",user: google_user, password: google_password)
    s = workbook.sheets[0] # assuming first sheet in workbook
    send_event('catchup_data', {current: s.cell('B',2) })
    send_event('bounce_back', {current: s.cell('B',3) )
end


SCHEDULER.every '5m' do
    fetch_spreadsheet_data()
end
```